# AOS.js with Bootstrap-Column with hover-effect

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, aos.js

I have the following layout:
[image: layout]

Each box is a bootstrap `col-sm-4` with the hover-effect `transform: scale(1.05)` and the transition `transition: transform ease-in-out .25s` (like the box in the top left corner). Now I want to add a AOS-flip-in-effect `data-aos="flip-left" data-aos-easing="ease-out-cubic" data-aos-duration="3000" data-aos-delay="50"`. What is a possibility to have different transition-durations for these both transitions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My result was to add the AOS-flip-effect to the container of the `.col-sm-4`